# mootools load by document id

Tags: javascript, html, css, mootools

I am simply trying use moo-tools to load some html content into an id based on a click event, but I can't seem to find my mistake.  The `alert('clicked')` works, so I know the click event is firing.

```js
window.addEvent('load', function(){
    $('deviceInfo').addEvent('click', function(){
        document.id('commands').load('deviceInfo.html');
        //alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

Click `id`:

```
<a href="#" id="deviceInfo">Information</a>
```

Target `id`:

```
<div id="commands">
    <p>something</p>
</div>
```

`deviceInfo.html` only contains:

```
<p>info</p>
```

Comment: What is your folder structure? Are you sure the file is in the same folder? Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: Both html pages are in the same level and I do not get any errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I stripped everything down and ran the function using only the mootools core library and it worked. So it is some kind of conflict between js libraries. So, mystery solved.